# Is there a way retrieve a value that falls between 2 dates?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a VBA code where I am given 2 dates to be used as a date range. Using this date range, I am trying to compare it to a date in every row within a table. If the table date is within the date range, I want to retrieve a specific value also within the table.

Example:

Date Range:
02/01/2021 - 07/01/2021

The colors are in Column A and the dates are in column B

Red  - 03/08/2021
Orange - 09/01/2021

For this example, I need it to return "Red"

Comment: Sharing the code that you have so far would be a good idea. In your case it may help us to understand how you are given the two dates and what you plan to do with the result i.e. there maybe multiple results, so how will you store those results, what will you do with them, or are you just trying to find the first occurrence...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is...

If you try it, remember to first set the correct values on the CONFIG sections of the code.

```
Sub RetrieveValue()

Dim start_date, end_date As Date
Dim dates_col, db_start_row, db_end_row As Integer
Dim counter, values_col, retrieve_values_col As Integer

'CONFIG THIS BEFORE YOU RUN THE MACRO
'--------------------------
retrieve_values_col = 4   'column number where you want to retrieve the values
values_col = 2            'column where all the values are
dates_col = 3             'in what column are the dates?
db_start_row = 3          'in what row does the data start?
start_date = Date - 4     'set the date interval
end_date = Date + 3       'DATE is a function that returns todays date
'--------------------------

db_end_row = Cells(Rows.Count, dates_col).End(xlUp).Row

For counter = db_start_row To db_end_row

    If Cells(counter, dates_col) >= _
    start_date And Cells(counter, dates_col) <= end_date Then
    
        Cells(counter, retrieve_values_col) = Cells(counter, values_col)
        
    End If

Next counter

End Sub
```

The dates must be set like in the following picture for the macro to work.

[image]